# how to work around missing type constraint on T saying "there is an implicit conversion to T"

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have an own class and I need to use a bunch of other classes that I cannot modify. I have written implicit conversions from my own type to the other types:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static implicit operator YourClass(MyClass m) => new YourClass();
    public static implicit operator HisClass(MyClass m) => new HisClass();
}
```

(In reality all classes have members, but I omit them here in favour of brevity.)

Now I can do this:

```
var mine = new MyClass();
YourClass yours = mine; // implicit conversion takes place
```

So far, so good.

Now I want to write a conversion method from some generic class (that I cannot modify) instance of `MyType` to any of the abovementioned other classes, so that I can do this:

```
var listOfMine = new List<MyClass>();
List<YourClass> listOfYours = Convert<YourClass>(listOfMine);
```

(In reality the generic class in question is not `List`.)

I'd *love to* write it like this:

```
public static List<T> Convert<T>(List<MyClass> listOfMine)
    where T : MyClass_has_implicit_conversion_to
{
    List<T> listOfT = new List<T>();
    foreach (var mine in listOfMine)
        listOfT.Add(mine); // implicit conversion takes place
    return listOfT;
}
```

, i.e. tell the compiler: `T` can be any class for which there is an implicit conversion from `MyClass` to `T`.

But since such a type constraint does not exist, I cannot tell the compiler that a conversion from `MyClass` to `T` is legal. So it complains:

> compiler error CS1503: Argument 'mine' cannot convert from MyClass to T.

**So what do I do?**

I know I can pacify the compiler by doing

```
listOfT.Add((T)(object)mine);
```

, but then I get a runtime error - my implicit conversion is never called in that case.

---

If I need to do the conversion in a different way (i.e. explicit conversion, method like `ToYourClass`, ..), I can live with that.

But I need the conversion outside of the `Convert<T>` method, so that I do not need to repeat myself if I create several such `Convert<T>` methods (e.g. one for `List<T>`, one for `T[]`, one for `Tuple<int,T>`, ...).

Comment: Use `dynamic` maybe? It would have to calculate the conversion at runtime, so this seems like the only option. Or you can forgo generics and just write a normal function, I see no reason why it is necessary

Comment: @Charlieface Updated my question. I want the `Convert` method to be generic because it should convert to all of the other classes, not just `YourClass`. In reality, I have many more than just two.

Comment: Is having an implicit conversion really that important to you? Why not just have an interface with a method `ConvertToMyClass`?

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe you should have read my question more carefully... No, implicit conversion is not important, see second last sentence (first sentence below the horizontal line). Why not have an interface - because I cannot modify the classes in question.

Comment: Your convert method can't be done as the compiler doesn't know of any relationship between the two types. So you need to specify a function to convert between them. It sounds like [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) does what you need?

Comment: @CharlesMager Can you elaborate? I don't see how `Enumerable.Select` can help here.

Comment: If you do not want to use Linq to project the elements, you can write extensionmethods for the types you want to provide conversion for.

Comment: @Kjara for your list example, `List<YourClass> listOfYours = listOfMine.Select(x => (YourClass)x).ToList()`. That uses your implicit conversion, but you could write the conversion inline or use a method / extension method.

Comment: @CharlesMager There is nothing generic in your example. I want a generic method that converts `List<MyClass>` to `List<T>`. And if I do `List<T> listOfT = listOfMine.Select(x => (T)x).ToList()` I just get CS1503.

Comment: The reason for that is that the compiler cannot statically figure out which of the conversion operators to call. You will have to do this dynamically at runtime, hence all the hints about dynamic and reflection and filtering. The compiler will **not** compile in a "if this then that, else this other" thing here, it will compile in a call to a conversion operator, but it doesn't know which one to choose, and thus you get an error. Simply put, you can't do this. `dynamic` will figure out the right operator at runtime, that's the closest you get.

Comment: I can't reproduce any error - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XL8BMw). As I explained in the comment, what you want isn't possible at compile time - you need to specify the conversion. `Select` is one of the simplest ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Mager's comment

> Your convert method can't be done as the compiler doesn't know of any relationship between the two types. So you need to specify a function to convert between them.

gave me the following idea:

```
public static List<T> Convert<T>(List<MyClass> listOfMine, Func<MyClass, T> Convert)
{
    List<T> listOfT = new List<T>();
    foreach (var mine in listOfMine)
        listOfT.Add(Convert(mine)); // manual conversion done here
    return listOfT;
}
```

That's quite alright, I can live with that.

Usage:

```
var listOfMine = new List<MyClass>();
List<YourClass> listOfYours = Convert<YourClass>(listOfMine, x => x);
```

`x => (YourClass)x` would be more explicit but not necessary since I have an implicit conversion defined. I could also define and use any `Func<MyClass, YourClass>` / `Func<MyClass, HisClass>` instead of implicit or explicit conversions.

Casting `mine` to `dynamic` is a nice idea as well (thanks Charlieface), but it's a source of errors due to missing compiler checks, so I'd like to avoid it if there are other ways.

Comment: This is [built-in to `List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=net-6.0) - `listOfMine.ConvertAll<YourClass>(x => x)` does the same.

Comment: @CharlesMager You have probably overlooked that part of my question: *In reality the generic class in question is not List.*